# Button to add gui element to exisitng one

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, widget, pmw

I have a window with some elements such as Label, ButtonBox etc packed in a group from Pmw module. I want to make such button that when clicked, it will extended the window and add another element (for example another Label) in the bottom OR in existing frame. Problem is that when clicked, nothing happens.

Here is the code with window

```
def __init__(self,
             page,
             groupname='myfirsttabdefault',
             defaultstructurename='',
             defaultchain=''
             ):

    group = Pmw.ScrolledFrame(page,
                              labelpos='nw',
                              label_text=groupname)
    self.groupname = groupname
    self.group = group

    group = Pmw.Group(page, tag_text = "Choose input file format")
    group.pack(fill='x', expand=1, padx=5, pady=5)
    prot_info = tk.Label(group.interior(), text='Single chain')
    prot_info.pack(padx=2, pady=2, expand='yes', fill='y')

    input_fileformat_buttons = Pmw.ButtonBox(group.interior(), padx=0)
    input_fileformat_buttons.add("original file", command=self.orig_button_click)
    input_fileformat_buttons.pack(fill='both', expand=1, padx=5, pady=1)
```

And here is the code for command orig_button_click

```
def orig_button_click(self):
    protein_info = tk.Label(self.group.interior(), text='something')
    protein_info.pack(padx=2, pady=2, expand='yes', fill='y')
```

**now the question: how to write a button that when clicked will add this protein_info element to existing window?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def orig_button_click(self):
    protein_info = tk.Label(self.group.interior(), text='something')
    protein_info.pack(padx=2, pady=2, expand='yes', fill='y')
    protein_info.bind("<Button-1>",self.Label_Click) #Bind the mouse click event. if you need only click label
def Label_Click(self):
    #Do stufff
    pass
```

Comment: this answer would be better if you added an explanation. What is different between this and what is in the question?

Comment: I missed protein_info.bind(...) function in my code :)

Comment: I explained it into the code. binding Mouse click event is missing